# Comparing a fk_id with id in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Want to compare two ids, if they are the same take only these rows and send them so i can print them out.

```
public IList<tbl_user> getLastc()
{

    var fk_id = (from m in dc.tbl_checkins orderby m.checkin_datetime descending select m.fk_user_id).Take(1);

    var result = (from c in dc.tbl_users
                 where c.user_id.Equals(fk_id)
                 select c).ToList();
        /*(from m in dc.tbl_users where m.user_id == fk_id select m).ToList();*/

    return result;
}
```

error:
The comparison operators are not supported for the type

> System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]].

Comment: @w0lf there was: 'De vergelijkingsoperators worden niet ondersteund voor het type' before

Comment: @w0lf There was some text not in english appended to the error, I removed it.

Comment: The comparison operators are not supported for the type, - Google Translator.This is the translated version of missing error .

Answer (score 2):

In `m.user_id == fk_id` one of this variables is nullable int, so if you want to compare them do

```
m.user_id!=null && user_id.Value==fk_id
```

it will check first if value is not null, then compare it's value with other value. Nullable values have also a property `HasValue` you can use it to determine if variable has value:

```
m.user_id.HasValue && user_id.Value==fk_id
```

note: if `fk_id` is nullable int change it with `m.user_id` (error does not say which is nullable int)

EDIT:

this is how it will fit:

```
(from m in 
dc.tbl_users where fk_id.HasValue && fk_id.Value==m.user_id select m).ToList()
```

EDIT2:

```
var fk_ids = (from m in dc.tbl_checkins orderby m.checkin_datetime descending select m.fk_user_id).Where(x=>x.HasValue).Select(x=>x.Value);

(from m in 
dc.tbl_users where fk_ids.Contains(m.user_id) select m).ToList()
```

Comment: @user3060452 which value is `nullable<int>`? Maybe fk_id is nullable and you should invert it as I suggested in my answer? See my edit

Comment: i need to cast it to int  var fk_id = (from m in dc.tbl_checkins orderby m.checkin_datetime descending select m.fk_user_id).Take(1); but how?

Comment: @user3060452 `var fk_id = (from m in dc.tbl_checkins orderby m.checkin_datetime descending select m.fk_user_id).First();` use it

Comment: what if i want to get more then 1 item?

Comment: @user3060452 `var fk_ids = (from m in dc.tbl_checkins orderby m.checkin_datetime descending select m.fk_user_id);` and then you can loop through fk_ids like: `foreach(var fk_id in fk_ids) { \\do whatever you want }` or use it however you want to

Comment: and what if i got multi same records in dc.tbl_checkins now i get only 2 names and i got 10 m.fk_user_id

Comment: @user3060452 you will get multiple rows from dc.tbl_checkins

Comment: @user3060452 make another question ... it was not a part of original question